# What is the correct way to: print "File size: $st->size" in perl?

Tags: perl

I'd like to know how to print the value of member `size` from a `File::stat` object, within double quotes.  I can `print "File size: " . $st->size` and get what I want:

> File size: 4003856350

But if I `print "File size: $st->size"`, I get:

> File size: File::stat=ARRAY(0x15bb4d8)->size

I've searched with terms like "perl print dereference", "perl print object member", "perl print arrow operator", and many other combinations.  I have tried using `$st->{size}`, but am informed that $st is not a hash.  I tried `$st->[size]`, since the original error seemed to indicate it's an array, but am told:

> Bareword "size" not allowed while "strict subs" in use

It seems like there should be a way for this to work within the quotes, and if so, I'd really like to know what it is.  I know I can use `printf` to do this without the concatenation, but after this much searching, trial, and error, my curiosity is piqued.

Sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use utf8;
use File::stat;

my $st = stat("/path/to/file");
print "File size: $st->size\n";
print "File size: " . $st->size . "\n";
printf "File size: %d\n", $st->size;
```

Comment: `use Data::Dumper;` and `print Dumper($st);` shows information like: `$VAR1 = bless( [ 16777220, 8603307603, 33188, 1, 501, 20, 0, 269, 1515052646, 1515052639, 1515052639, 4194304, 8 ], 'File::stat' );` — which is some sort of blessed object, not a hash ref. Which is why you get the complaints you do. I'm not sure what the fix is.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the `->size` is a method call, which isn't something you can interpolate

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Perl objects are traditionally blessed hash references, but you can actually bless any type of reference to create an object. In this particular case, your `Dumper` output shows that `File::stat` uses a blessed array reference.

Comment: I'd just write `print "File size: ", $st->size, "\n";` -- or, if you can assume Perl 5.10 or later: `say "File size: ", $st->size;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put Perl code in double quotes and expect it to be executed unless you somehow involve `eval EXPR`.

```
my $x = 4;
my $y = 5;
print "Sum: $x + $y\n";   # Prints Sum: 4 + 5, not Sum: 9.
```

The following work:

```
print "File size: " . $st->size . "\n";

print "File size: ".( $st->size )."\n";

say "File size: " . $st->size;

printf "File size: %s\n", $st->size;

Template->new()->process(\"File size: [% st.size %]\n", { st => $st });

print "File size: ${\( $st->size )}\n";
```

Please avoid the last one. It's wasteful, it evaluates the expression in list context even though it looks like it calls it in scalar context (which leads to surprises), and it makes your code less readable in practice. It is the least correct of the above ways. I'm only including it because I know someone else will post it if I don't.

Comment: Heh, <grin>. I would to use: `print "File size: @{[ $st->size ]}\n";` :)

Comment: In your last version, the parentheses aren't actually needed. `say "size: ${\$st->size}"` works, too. Does that version also have the "hidden list context" issue? (I assume it does, but just checking, since it's not a construct I'm personally familiar with. I tend to use explicit concatenation rather than interpolation for anything other than simple scalars.)

Answer (score 0):

@ikegami has provided more than enough ways of printing what you want. But maybe the reason why you don't get interpolation within the double quotes is not clear. The `->` operator in Perl is overloaded and has more than one use:

1. If `$hash` is a hash ref, `$hash->{key}` or even `$hash->{'key'}` will access the key `key`.
2. If `$array` is an array ref, `$array->[N]` will access index `N`.
3. If `My::Module` is a module, `My::Module->member` will access `member` within the module. This way any function of the module may be accessed even if not exported.
4. Finally, if `$object` is an object, `$object->member` will access `member` related to that object instance.

So `$st->size` is accessing the member `size` of the object of type `File::stat`. In this case `size` is a method (function) that is being executed on `$st`, its object instance. String interpolation happens with variables, so:

```
print "File size: $st->size\n";
```

Prints the value of `$st`, which is `File::stat=ARRAY(0x15bb4d8)` (the address of the ref may vary) and then the rest of the string `->size\n`. The function invocation will be clear if we use `$st->size()` which is equivalent.

As pointed out, to get the result of the function invocation we need to keep that piece of code outside of the doble quotes, like:

```
print 'File size: ' . $st->size . "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, Javier.  I do understand that it was accessing only $st rather than the whole $st->size from the output, which is why I thought perhaps the File::stat object was an array at first.  I clearly have much learning to do on the fundamentals of Perl.

Comment: Re "*which is why I thought perhaps the File::stat object was an array at first*", It is, but you shouldn't go about messing with the internals of objects.

Comment: @SiliconBadger, the explanation is there for anyone to read it... Perl is by no means simple. It gets the work done but it is also full of traps. As ikegami says, libraries should be used by means of the methods provided. Trying to guess at their implementation details is asking for trouble.

Comment: @JavierElices I wasn't trying to guess at anything which is intended to be

Comment: It wasn't my intention to access anything which is intended to be obscured/protected/private.  My background is more C/C++, so when I saw the term "array", I merely thought that _might_ indicate that I should treat it as such, even though it didn't seem right.  If I don't follow the leads I have (within reasonable time), I'd be posting all kinds of pointless questions on here, getting downvoted, and seeing comments like "you didn't think to try treating it as an array based on the output?"  Which is similar to: "the explanation is there for anyone to read it".  ;-)

Comment: @SiliconBadger, I am sorry if my writting did not sound good to you. By "the explanation is there for anyone to read it" I mean that Stack Overflow questions / answers style is meant to be a way for many people to find good questions and good answers. When I write an answer I have other readers in mind, not only the person asking the question. A good answer may be useful to others looking for the same thing. That's all. :-)

Comment: @JavierElices: I understand now, I'm sorry for being defensive.  I appreciate your assistance!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

use the Baby Cart

> Discovered by Larry Wall, 1994. (Alternate nicknames: "shopping-trolley", "pram", "turtle")

it gets the job done in almost any situation where you need to print the result of a method:

```
print "File size: @{[ $st->size ]}\n"
```

see: [Perl Secrets](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod)